# Why don't websites use Vary: Accept-Language?

Tags: http, http-headers, multilingual

As far as I know you should aways set the `Vary: Accept-language` response header when working on a multi-language website. In my case the user gets redirected to a language specific page, e.g. http://www.example.com/nl/.

But I can't find any website that uses this `Vary` header. Why is that? Even the multi-language websites from Apple, Microsoft, Samsung, Facebook don't use this header.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is that websites only support a small subset of the possible languages, which would mean web caches (ie. CDNs) would have to cache many many different versions of a page based on the Accept-Language header coming from the browser, when in reality there would only be few different versions. This is a problem because it causes cache fragmentation, which reduces cache hit ratio on the caching servers and consumes more resources  (CPU/RAM/Disk).

Also Google recommends using a different url per language 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192

Also Akamai used to not support caching based on the Vary header, except for Vary: Accept-Encoding, however I don't believe they still has this limitation.
http://my.globaldots.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=32

Comment: "websites only support a small subset of the possible languages" That's a moot argument: The content of the `Content-Language` header is supposed to be part of the cache key. However, intermediaries only have to keep a cached copy if it has been requested at least once. They do not need to proactively retrieve every language version. Still a solid answer: +1

Comment: You can simplify the list of accepted languages in reverse-proxies, such as Varnish. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html for instance. So, if you have a few languages on the backend (webserver), you may filter these in Varnish, then you can rely on the filtered value. And Varnish will only cache the allowed ones. But @Shawn's answer is very true in the common case.

Answer (score -1):

You can normalize Vary: Accept-Language in a similar way:

```
# Normalize Accept-Language
declare local var.lang STRING;
if (req.http.Accept-Language) {
  set var.lang = req.http.Accept-Language;
}
if (var.lang ~ "^da") {
  set req.http.Accept-Language = "da";
} elsif (var.lang ~ "^sv") {
  set req.http.Accept-Language = "sv";
} else {
  # unknown language
  remove req.http.Accept-Language;
}
```